# I want to restore the "All My Files" folder/view to the finder sidebar

Tags: finder, search, sidebar

While I've had my ups and downs with the "All My Files" folder in the Mac sidebar, it is a really useful tool for unclogging my hard drive of large files - this is especially important because of the small hard drive in the Macbook Air I'm now using.

Some time ago, the "All My Files" folder/view completely disappeared from the finder sidebar, and I havent' been able to figure out how or why, or restore it to finder.

Because of my search for an answer, I'm now learning about creating smart folders, which is great, but I still can't figure out how to create an "All My Files" smart folder, which *REALLY* shows all the files on the Mac!

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 4):

Go to the Finder Preferences, go to the Sidebar tab, and then make sure the "All My Files" box is checked:

[image]

Comment: Make screenshot of windows using Command-Shift-4, release, than hit Spacebar. This will make it possible to get rid of the ugly background ;) +1 for the simple solution.

Comment: My Finder has All My Files checked, but they STILL do not appear in the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

The High Sierra finder sidebar doesn't have a choice for 'All My Files' as Sierra did; it has been replaced with 'Recent'

Comment: I confirm - and it's very bad move